# driver.get function in selenium on windows 10 is not opening the desired address

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox

I am using Selenium to web scrape a database, however, the `driver.get()` command does not actually go to the address I am trying to reach. My script runs successfully i.e. without an error but it should open https://www.python.org/ (in this example) but instead, it opens [How to change your default browser to Firefox on Windows](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-change-your-default-browser-firefox-windows?utm_source=firefox-browser&utm_medium=firefox-browser&utm_campaign=redirect&utm_content=windows10-welcome-tab&redirectslug=how-change-your-default-browser-windows-10&redirectlocale=en-US) :(

When I set `options.headless = True` to `false`, I do not get a headless start and am instead directed to another [address](http://www6.54956.com/?template=ARROW_3&tdfs=1&s_token=1656458387.0240930000&uuid=1656458387.0240930000&searchbox=1&showDomain=1) I am not trying to reach. I imagine this would be easier on Linux but due to the database I am accessing the only way my IT department says it can be done is through Windows.

#### Script

```py
import selenium

from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service as FirefoxService
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary

options = Options()
options.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=FirefoxService(GeckoDriverManager().install()), options=options)

driver.get("http://www.python.org")
print('driver Title:',driver.title)
print('Driver name:',driver.name)
print('Driver URL:',driver.current_url)
driver.quit()
```

#### Environment

```yaml
name: apex2
channels:
  - defaults
  - conda-forge
dependencies:
  - async_generator=1.10=py_0
  - attrs=21.4.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - beautifulsoup4=4.11.1=pyha770c72_0
  - blas=1.0=mkl
  - bottleneck=1.3.4=py310h206c3e8_0
  - brotlipy=0.7.0=py310hc431981_1002
  - bs4=4.11.1=hd8ed1ab_0
  - bzip2=1.0.8=he774522_0
  - ca-certificates=2018.4.16=0
  - certifi=2022.6.15=py310h9f7ea03_0
  - cffi=1.15.0=py310hc431981_1
  - charset-normalizer=2.0.12=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - click=7.1.2=pyh9f0ad1d_0
  - cryptography=36.0.0=py310h1ff2cf0_0
  - h11=0.13.0=pyhd8ed1ab_1
  - idna=3.3=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - intel-openmp=2021.4.0=h9f7ea03_3556
  - libffi=3.4.2=h6986bd8_4
  - mkl=2021.4.0=h9f7ea03_640
  - mkl-service=2.4.0=py310hdb075cb_0
  - mkl_fft=1.3.1=py310h3b26ad3_0
  - mkl_random=1.2.2=py310h59b8b6a_0
  - numexpr=2.8.1=py310hba4fa53_2
  - numpy=1.22.3=py310h54a06cd_0
  - numpy-base=1.22.3=py310hb81b812_0
  - openssl=1.1.1o=hc431981_0
  - outcome=1.2.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - packaging=21.3=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - pandas=1.4.2=py310h6986bd8_0
  - pip=22.1.2=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - pycparser=2.21=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - pyopenssl=22.0.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - pyparsing=3.0.9=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - pysocks=1.7.1=py310h9f7ea03_0
  - python=3.10.4=hdf15aeb_0
  - python-dateutil=2.8.2=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - python-dotenv=0.20.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - pytz=2022.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - requests=2.28.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - selenium=4.3.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - setuptools=61.2.0=py310h9f7ea03_0
  - six=1.16.0=pyh6c4a22f_0
  - sniffio=1.2.0=py310h9f7ea03_1
  - sortedcontainers=2.4.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - soupsieve=2.3.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - sqlite=3.38.3=hc431981_0
  - tk=8.6.12=hc431981_0
  - trio=0.19.0=py310h9f7ea03_0
  - trio-websocket=0.9.2=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - typing_extensions=4.2.0=pyha770c72_1
  - tzdata=2022a=h191b570_0
  - urllib3=1.26.9=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - vc=14.2=h21ff451_1
  - vs2015_runtime=14.27.29016=h5e58377_2
  - webdriver-manager=3.7.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - wheel=0.37.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - win_inet_pton=1.1.0=py310h9f7ea03_0
  - wincertstore=0.2=py310h9f7ea03_2
  - wsproto=0.14.0=py_0
  - xz=5.2.5=h559d222_1
  - zlib=1.2.11=vc14_0
prefix: C:\Users\Noah Siegel\.conda\envs\apex2
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the most recent Selenium no longer supports newer versions of Firefox which suggests that newer versions of geckodriver are unnecessary as mentioned in this [post](https://www.edureka.co/community/37805/what-versions-of-firefox-browser-supported-by-selenium-ide).

I was able to get my code running after using an older geckodriver and running an older Firefox executable.

```py
import selenium

from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

# Install Geckodriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=GeckoDriverManager(version="v0.20.0").install())

driver.get("http://www.python.org")
print('driver Title:',driver.title)
print('Driver name:',driver.name)
print('Driver URL:',driver.current_url)
driver.quit()
```